# If HTML box is checked, show that tag at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with different cells. In the cells are an options to select OK, FIXED or INCOMPLETE. If the INCOMPLETE cell is checked, I'm able to add that ID to an array, but I'm not sure how to then print that array at the bottom of the page. I feel like I will have to have a button that when clicked, it will then print out all the id's at the bottom of the page instead of being able to do this automatically.

```
var all_checked = new Array();
  function add_checked(el) {
    all_checked.push(el.id);
  }
<form action="/action_page.php">
<table id="t01" width="1200" height="10" border="3">
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>DETAILS</th>
  <th>OK</th>
  <th>FIXED</th>
  <th>INCOMPLETE</th>
  <th>N/A</th>
  <th>NOTES</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>MOTOR &amp; REDUCER-</b>Are correct and installed properly.</td>
  <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK22" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></form></td>
  <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK23" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK24" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK25" onclick="ckChange(this);add_checked(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td width="15%">
    <textarea placeholder="Type notes and remarks." cols="55"></textarea>
  </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td><b>REDUCER LUBRICATION-</b>Reducer is filled with oil (Mobil SHC 634/ISO VG 460)(ISS 0.7).</td>
  <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK26" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></form></td>
  <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK27" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK28" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK29" onclick="ckChange(this);add_checked(this)" type="checkbox"><br></td>
  <td>
    <textarea placeholder="Type notes and remarks." cols="55"></textarea>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ckChange is not defined`

Comment: your table format is wrong. the number of td in each row doesn't match with the number of th

Comment: Please add the code for `ckChange`.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to solve the problem. Maybe the problem is from the function ckChange.
The only thing I can remind you is that there are two unnecessary "form" tag in the follow.

```
<td><input name="INS1" id="CHK22" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></form></td>

<td><input name="INS2" id="CHK26" onclick="ckChange(this)" type="checkbox"><br></form></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used unobtrusive principles to add an event listener.

Then we grab the checked elements and create an array the update the `innerHTML` property of an element to display the result.

```js
//Get all checkboxes in the table
var targetCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#t01 input[type=checkbox]"); 

//Get our display element
var resultElement = document.querySelector("#results span");

//Method to get and display the checked elements
function displayChecked(){
  //Get Checked boxes;
  var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#t01 input[type=checkbox]:checked"); 
  var ids = [];
  checkedBoxes.forEach(function(box){
    ids.push(box.id);
  });
  
  //Update result element
  resultElement.innerHTML = ids.join();
}

//Add Event LIstener to the check boxes
targetCheckBoxes.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click",displayChecked, false);
})
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <table id="t01" width="1200" height="10" border="3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>DETAILS</th>
        <th>OK</th>
        <th>FIXED</th>
        <th>INCOMPLETE</th>
        <th>N/A</th>
        <th>NOTES</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>MOTOR &amp; REDUCER-</b>Are correct and installed properly.</td>
        <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK22" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK23" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK24" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS1" id="CHK25" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
          <textarea placeholder="Type notes and remarks." cols="55"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>REDUCER LUBRICATION-</b>Reducer is filled with oil (Mobil SHC 634/ISO VG 460)(ISS 0.7).</td>
        <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK26" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK27" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK28" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="INS2" id="CHK29" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>
          <textarea placeholder="Type notes and remarks." cols="55"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div id="results">Results : <span></span></div>
```

On a side note, I've removed your `<br>` tags. You should be using CSS, specifically padding or margins for providing space.